# Using fill with multi dim arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, fill

Is it possible to use fill to pass in a array into an array of tuples in ruby using fill?

For example I am trying to combine the following two arrays using zip, and then plan on transposing them. I am trying the following

```
column_name_tuples = [["foo"], ["bar"]]
column_label_tuples = [["Foo Bar"]]
column_label_tuples.fill(column_name_tuples.size..column_label_tuples.size - 1) { [nil] }
```

This results in column labels being filled as follows

```
[["Foo Bar"], nil]
```

When in fact I need it to be filled like this so I can do a transpose afterwards

```
[["Foo Bar"], [nil]]
```

Comment: Best to format to avoid the need for the reader to scroll horizontally. I just did, but forgot to scroll back, so couldn't find `column_name_tuples`. All I saw were `n_label_tuples`. :-) Also, it's a courtesy to avoid the need to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
column_label_tuples.fill([nil], column_label_tuples.size,
  column_name_tuples.size-column_label_tuples.size)
  #=> now [["Foo Bar"], [nil]]
```

which reduces to:

```
column_label_tuples.fill([nil], 1, 2-1)
```

Comment: small bug in there but once it was fixed it did the trick ! Thanks !